# Angular DatePipe to print Datetime

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, doctrine

I get the next object from database:

```
{
  createdAt: {
    timezone : [...],
    timestamp: 'date value in timestamp'
  }
}
```

[image: object in json]

And i need to print the createdAt property in HTML with Angular 6 so i try next:
`{{obj.createdAt | date}}` but i get the next error:
`invalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Trying to debug this property with this statement `{{obj.createdAt | json}}` i get a long json object wich looks like this:

```
{ "timezone": { "name": "Europe/Berlin",
                "transitions": [..Long content here..]
}
```

**¿How can i print the correct dateTime?**

Im using Symfony with Doctrine in the Backend and mysql database. The property CreatedAt is a DateTime with this value:

[image: Database result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date value is encoded in timestamp;

You have to create a method

```
toDateIKnow(obj: any) {
    return new Date(obj.createdAt.timestamp);
}
```

Then in your html file

```
{{toDateIKnow(obj) | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Comment: the solution was this. The value was in child property `createdAt.timestamp`. Thanks for helping me to find int